# Display Name And Email Address Not The Same

Tags: email, exchange, outlook

Our office has Exchange 2003 with SP2.
Workstation has Office 2010.

When I open up an email I receive from one of our external clients and reply to the email, one of the email receipients "email address" is translated incorrectly.

When I click on the Email Address to get E-mail Properties in Outlook:

the Display Name is bob.barker@priceisright.com

BUT

the E-mail Address "Bob Barker"@mydomain.com  (Where mydomain.com is the domain of my exchange server).

Any ideas what I need to change on our Exchange server?

Answer (score 3):

For Exchange 2003 that setting would be under exchange system manager -> recipient policies -> default policy properties.  On the email addresses tab, make sure the SMTP address is correct and set to primary. Then run update now on the recipient update service to push out the change.

You can also set this per user in AD users/computers for the account on the email addresses tab.

Comment: I wouldn't neccessarily check the Recipient Policy first, unless the problem is affecting all users.

Comment: Good point - but this should be set correctly anyway...

Comment: True. Trust but verify.

Comment: I checked the Recipient Policy and it's set correctly.  This problem appears for only inbound email address - where it's using the display name but replacing the ending of the email address with our corporate email address domain.

Answer (score 1):

Check the primary SMTP address on the Email Addresses tab of the user account properties and make sure the correct email address is set as the primary SMTP address.